# HTML Special characters to HTML entities to prevent XSS vulnerabilites

Tags: eclipse, xss

In order to minimize XSS vulnerabilities of my application, and as there are no user inputs at all I'm performing HTML-Entity escaping of my output as below, but my html breaks and displays nothing and if I replace  to <script> the whole code appears in the output as is.

document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = "JAVA";
document.getElementById(&quot;dis&quot;).innerHTML = &quot;JAVA&quot;;

If this is not the right way please suggest the steps for using the public method below for HTML escaping to minimize the XSS vulnerabilities.

public static String escapeHtml (CharSequence text)

Comment: "there are no user inputs at all" If that's true, why would your output be insecure then?

Comment: Alexander, I was suggested on the site for my question 26675128 to escape the output to minimize XSS attacks.